# iPhone X issues when using a UITextView in an inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, keyboard, iphone-x, inputaccessoryview

I'm trying to make a user interface similar to Messages where an input bar is pinned to the top of the keyboard, yet still appears at the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is dismissed. The approach I'd like to use involves setting the 'inputAccessoryView' property of my view controller with a view that contains a UITextView. This seems to work well on devices other than an iPhone X. Sometimes on the iPhone X, the keyboard when raised, shows the bottom row ('123', 'space' and 'return') of keys displayed at the very bottom of the screen below the safe area. The Globe and Microphone icons are drawn over the bottom row. I've included a screenshot showing this issue below. Pressing 'return' to add an extra line in the text view seems to reset the keyboard to its proper layout.

I'm wondering if there is a good workaround for this issue. The following code can be used to demonstrate the problem (replace the contents of ViewController.Swift of the project generated from the "Single View App" project template):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private var textViewInputAccessoryView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 44)))

  override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return textViewInputAccessoryView
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textViewInputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you test this on a real iOS device? looks like a sim bug

Comment: Thanks! It sure looks like a Simulator bug. I was able to repro the same issue using the Messages app on the iPhone X Simulator. This doesn't seem to happen on an iPhone X device.